# Spark Dataset selective recompute

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I know that Spark knows how to distribute work needed to be done on a new node that is started up in case of another node failure for example.

I would like to know if this can be utilized in other use cases.

Assume I have a tree of transformations and actions. What happens when one of the datasets/dataframes gets updated (e.g. new file was imported). In this case I would like to repeat only those transformations and actions that are impacted and linked to this change. Other non related transformations and actions should be used from cache as they were not impacted.

Now, should I had only a few of these dataframes and transformations and actions I can do it manually. But I have a few dozens or more such DF and actions ans I am trying to understand if spark has something built in within the framework that can help me out here.

Here is an example of my code:

```
val carLines = spark
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(carLineSchema)
  .csv("src/test/resources/cars")

val ageMappingFunction: Int => String = (age: Int) => if (age > 80) "old" else "young"
//
val _age = udf.register("_age", ageMappingFunction)

val personLines = spark
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(personLineSchema)
  .csv("src/test/resources/persons")
  .withColumn("_age", _age($"age"))

val accidentsLines = spark
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .schema(accidentLineSchema)
  .csv("src/test/resources/accidents")

val carOwners = personLines
  .withColumnRenamed("id", "driver_id")
  .join(carLines, Seq("driver_id"), "left")
  .withColumnRenamed("id", "car_id")
  .withColumnRenamed("car_make", "car_maker")
  .withColumnRenamed("driver_id", "id")
```

Now for some transformations:

```
 val accidentsWithDrivers = accidentsLines
  .join(personLines.withColumnRenamed("id", "driver_id"), "driver_id")

 val accidentsPerDriverID = accidentsWithDrivers
  .groupBy("driver_id")
  .agg(Map(
    "name" -> "count"
  ))
  .withColumnRenamed("count(name)", "accident_count")
  .withColumnRenamed("driver_id", "id")

 val finalTable = carOwners
  .join(numberOfCarsPerDriver, Seq("id", "name", "age", "_age"))
  .join(accidentsPerDriverID, "id")
```

Then I do some actions (for simplicity I'll use 'show'):

```
carOwners.show(true)
numberOfCarsPerDriver.show(true)
finalTable.show(true)
```

So - what I'm asking is what if `accidentsLines` has changed but not `carLines` or `personLines`. Can we do the `carOwners` transformation with cached values of `carLines` and `personLines`?

IN OTHER WORDS:
Can I somehow use RDD#cache() api to survive between different driver runs assuming I want to keep it in-memory within spark cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I need to either use [job-server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) or use IgniteRDD support from Apache Ignite:

```
//WRITE
val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(spark.sparkContext, "ignite-config.xml", true)
val schema = dataframe.schema
val rdd = dataframe.rdd
igniteContext.ignite().getOrCreateCache("ignite-cache").put("schema", schema)
igniteContext.fromCache(name).saveValues(rdd)

//READ
 val schema = igniteContext.ignite()
    .getOrCreateCache[String, StructType]("ignite-cache")
    .get("schema")
    .asInstanceOf[StructType]

  val igniteRdd: IgniteRDD[String, Row] = igniteContext.fromCache(name)
  val rdd = igniteRdd.map(a => a._2)
  val dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```